# Gas estimation failed

Tags: solidity

So i started reading the book Mastering Ethereum and followed the guide by creating a faucet contract.

I used the code suggested in the book:

```
 
// SPDX-License-Identifier: CC-BY-SA-4.0

// Version of Solidity compiler this program was written for
pragma solidity 0.6.4;

// Our first contract is a faucet!
contract Faucet {
   // Accept any incoming amount
   receive() external payable {}

   // Give out ether to anyone who asks
   function withdraw(uint withdraw_amount) public {
       // Limit withdrawal amount
       require(withdraw_amount <= 100000000000000000);

       // Send the amount to the address that requested it
       msg.sender.transfer(withdraw_amount);
   }
}
```

But whenever i try to deploy ethereum to the contract it says that gas estimation failed and it gives me this error: creation of Faucet errored: MetaMask Tx Signature: User denied transaction signature

I researched it already but cant find a solution to this problem. Whenever i try to create the faucet the transaction execution fails.

Maybe someone can help me ? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Contract code deployment worked fine for me... I used:

- https://remix.ethereum.org/ IDE
- Rinkeby network
- Brave browser version 1.28.105